# Using imaplib, how can I create a mailbox without the \\NoSelect attribute

Tags: python, gmail, imaplib, gmail-imap

I'm attempting to create directory trees in an gmail IMAP account. I've used the "create()" command in imaplib, but it seems to add the \\Noselect attribute to the created folder. This breaks gmail's nested labels feature - is there a way to remove the \\Noselect attribute, or avoid it being created in the first place?

Example:

```
>> imap.create("foo/bar")
('OK', [b'Success'])
>> imap.list()
[b'(\\Noselect \\HasChildren) "/" "foo"', b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" "foo/bar"',...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out a solution - Not sure if it's the 'best' way though. When creating a nested mailbox in one command, the top level mailboxes automatically are flagged \\Noselect. While it may be hacky, you can remove this flag by creating each level explicitly.

Example:

```
folder = "abc/def/ghi/jkl"

target = ""

for level in folder.split('/'):
    target += "{}/".format(level)
    imap.create(target)
```

I'll leave the question open to see if anyone has a better solution.

Comment: This did not work for me, because my IMAP provider forbids more than 3 levels of directories. I don't know if this is a common limitation, but it includes Thunderbird and is something anyone messing with IMAP Subdirectories should know.
The only reference on this I found is in german https://www.thunderbird-mail.de/forum/thread/91017-unterordner-erstellen/

Answer (score 2):

bjeanes: Sam's solution works for me as long as I leave off the trailing hierarchy delimiter.

So, if I want to create the nested folder a/b/c, I first create just plain "a". If I do an xlist, it has the hasNoChildren flag set. Now I create "a/b", and an xlist will now show "a" with the "hasChildren" flag set, and "a/b" with the "hasNoChildren" flag set. Finally, I create "a/b/c", and now "b" has the "hasChildren" flag set as well. A look at the gmail web interface confirms this as well.

Sam: thanks for figuring this out and posting the solution. "Hacky" beats "not working." :^)